# FAB does not resolve intents

Tags: android, android-intent

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteViewFragment.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD_EXTRA, FragmentToLaunch.CREATE);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

under `Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteViewFragment.class);`, i get an error *cannot resolve constructor* if I dont put this intent command in the fab, it will work. Why and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: did u try `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteViewFragment.class);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the place of the intent creation. 
You are creating the intent inside an onclicklistener, so the "this" you are referring to is not your Activity but the onClickListener.

Fix it by using ActivityName.this instead of this.